# What does "gingery" mean in the context of this comic?

Tags: word-usage

This question is about [todays FoxTrot comic](http://www.foxtrot.com/2015/12/20/spicy/).

Jason creates [Gingerbread man cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gingerbread_man) with blue pants, funny hair styles and chocolate freckles and explains that he "likes his gingerbread men to be extra gingery".

I know what [Ginger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginger) is, and I looked up [possible meanings of *gingery* in the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gingery) (spicy; lively; the color of ginger), but  I still don't get the joke.

Comment: Note: I did not directly include the comic in the question (as an image rather than a link), since I am not familiar enough with US copyright law to know whether this qualifies as "fair use" or not. If anyone feels confident enough, feel free to edit my question (and bear the consequences, if any ;-)).

Comment: *Ginger* also means "redhead"--note that the cookies have orange hair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not much of a "joke". The allusion is to the fact that ginger-haired people are [stereotypically associated with having freckles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hair).

Comment: @StoneyB: Error 404. Did you mean [this?](https://johnnysaye.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/the-legend-of-the-soulless-ginger/) Personally, although I can understand (but not approve of) racism in general, I've never been able to get my head around the idea that there's something undesirable about redheads. It's like being prejudiced against people with, say, brown eyes.

Comment: Sorry 'bout that - I never can keep track of how to insert links. I don't think in this case it's distaste for redheads but distaste for redheaded-kids-that-look-like-Alfred-E-Neuman-subbing-into-the-Andy-Griffith-Show.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that they have funny hair styles, so much as they are given red (aka 'ginger') hair.

So they've been given ginger flavouring, and also been given ginger hair.